# List of all traditional Chinese characters

Tags: characters, traditional-characters, database

I'm looking for a repository or database containing all traditional Chinese characters. Where can I find this?

Comment: What do you want them for? Do you want to include extremely obscure characters that most Chinese don't know at all (e.g. those in [CJK Unified Ideographs Extension E](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U2B820.pdf))? Do you want to include relatively well-known characters that aren't in Unicode, such as [biang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biangbiang_noodles#Chinese_character_for_bi.C3.A1ng)?

Comment: FYI, there are over 80,000 Chinese characters in Unicode, the great majority of them is traditional, but there are still some characters that aren't covered.

Comment: Actually I'm looking for just the standard traditional characters used nowadays in Hong Kong and Taiwan.  I've found them,  but I'm also looking for Chinese handwriting images to compare their accuracy to the text format,  any ideas of this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. Download [CJSYS-20110919.zip](http://www.chinesecj.com/forum/forum.php?mod=attachment&aid=NzE3fGVkZjhjN2U1fDE0ODQ3MzU1OTZ8MHwyNTk2).
2. Find /CJSYS-20110919/cjsys/yong/mb/cj5-13053.txt
3. Copy the [DATA] section (from line 9 to 14136) into a spreadsheet.
4. Remove whatever you don't need.
5. Sort.
6. Remove duplicates.

source: [倉頡平台2012](http://www.chinesecj.com/forum/forum.php?mod=viewthread&tid=2596)

By the way,

cj5-8300.txt has the simplified characters. (8300餘個簡體漢字)

cj5-20902.txt includes both of them. (國際標準碼20902個簡繁漢字)

cj5-70000.txt includes the rare-used characters. (國際標準碼75000個簡繁中日韓越漢字)

cj5-ftzk.txt is a table of the traditional phrases. (繁體詞庫)

cj5-jtzk.txt is a table of the simplified phrases. (簡體詞庫)

Comment: Thanks so much Himen!  If I'm ONLY  lookin for traditional Chinese characters,  how may I find it?  Thanks.  For example can it filter out simplified and traditional?

Comment: Just follow the steps I listed above, and you can get what you are looking for.
They are traditional Chinese characters only, so you don't have to filter anything.
There are 14127 entries left, however, as the filename claimed, there are only 13053 different characters.
Thus, you have to sort and then remove the duplicates.

Comment: The resources gave by 水巷孑蠻 are also very good. 1. Download the zip file (dict_revised_2015_20160523.zip). 2. Open the first file (dict_revised_2015_20160523_1.xls). 3. The entries starting from C2 to C11934 are what you are looking for.
There are some pictorial characters and some duplicates.
Besides those, there are 9875 different characters,.

Comment: Hi hinen., maybe I should elaborate.  Now that we found the computer characters,  is it possible to get the hand written characters online?  I want to compare handwritten characters to the digital characters.  Any idea where I can find sample of handwritten Chinese characters online?  Thanks!

Comment: The hand written characters should be pictures.
It's not easy to find all the ten thousand pictures.
An alternative method is to use computer fonts which are in the hand written style.
The most common Chinese font is 明體, I think.
The most formal and common font is 楷體, which is in the hand written style.
If you have learned Chinese for a while, you should know these.

Comment: The (Taiwan) official font can be downloaded from [the official site](http://depart.moe.edu.tw/ed2400/News_Content.aspx?n=8940E5C0456177C3&sms=893AAA1CBFE149DE&s=DFBE7BE3EE0DB6AE).
If you like to compare one by one, [國學大師](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/zidian/) and [漢典](http://www.zdic.net/) can show the 楷體. 漢典 can even show the sequence of strokes.
(Sorry, I have to say something. Your questions are off-topic here.)

Comment: @hinen Sorry, I have to ask something. Why is it off-topic?

Answer (score 0):

you may download the 國語辭典, there're 4 excel files in the zip.

http://resources.publicense.moe.edu.tw/dict_reviseddict_download.html

for traditional chinese, this one is authoritative, and informative.

have fun :)

Comment: Will do! I see two links, should I download the first or second? what's the difference? Also, which of the 4 excel files contains only traditional chinese charactrs? Great, this one seems to have the words as well! thanks. But it seems the excel file only has simplified chinese text and pin yin

Answer (score 0):

If you are not wanting to download files to your computer (viruses, etc.) here's a website where you can search for them: http://www.zhongwen.com/